# Getting number of childs of an element with no ID with beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically I'm trying to scrape a webpage with Python and I'm getting stucked at finding the number of childs of one element in a list using BeautifulSoup, the HTML of the list follows this:

```
<table id="MyTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In my case I want to get the number of `tr` inside tag `tbody`, but since it has no id, I found no way to get it with soup and then do a `findAll("tr")`. Pretty sure this should be easy but can't find a way, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `len()` of your `resultSet` from selecting all `<tr>` in the `<tbody>`:

```
len(soup.select('#MyTable > tbody tr'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<table id="MyTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

len(soup.select('#MyTable > tbody tr'))
```

##### Output

```
7
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, knew it should be pretty simple but couldn't figure it out. Thanks again